# PDFLib Factory. Error when calling $this->pdf from functions within class

Tags: php, pdflib

The idea is as follows, to make a creation of PDFs a little bit cleaner, I am supposed to create a Factory/Abstract class that will a set of predefined functions like so

```
class AbstractPDF{
    
    protected $pdf;
    protected $searchpath;
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        $this->pdf = PDF_new();
        $this->searchpath = "fonts/";
        
        pdf_set_option($this->pdf,"errorpolicy=return");

        pdf_set_option($this->pdf,"searchpath={" . $this->searchpath . "}");

        pdf_set_option($this->pdf,"stringformat=utf8");
        
    }
    
    protected function startAFourPage(){
        
        pdf_begin_page_ext($this->pdf, 0, 0, "width=a4.width height=a4.height");
                }
    

    
    /* When setting up any of the PDF content types, one should */
    /* remember that in PDFLib, x=>y axis start with 0(zero) at */
    /* lower left corner.                                       */
    /* The text line is set up in space by setting up the       */
    /* coordinates of the lower left corner and then providing  */
    /* height and width of the object as separate values        */  
    


protected function setupTextLine($xcoordinate, $ycoordinate, $width, $height,
                        $fontName, $fontEncoding, $fontSize, $text, $textPosition = "left"){
        
        //adding text directly through the PDFLib documentation
        $font = PDF_load_font($this->pdf, $fontName, $fontEncoding, "");
        PDF_setfont($this->pdf, $font, $fontSize);
        //PDF_set_text_pos($this->pdf, 25, 650);
        //PDF_show($this->pdf, $text);
        PDF_fit_textline ($this->pdf, $text, 111, 744, "boxsize {".$width." ".$height."} position=left");
        
    }
    
    
    /* When setting up any of the PDF content types, one should */
    /* remember that in PDFLib, x=>y axis start with 0(zero) at */
    /* lower left corner.                                       */
    /* The text flow is set up by providing the coordinate for  */
    /* lower left corner and upper right, as a rule.            */
    /* But overall PDFLib will placed it by coordinates for     */
    /* two corners diagonal to each other.                      */
    /* For this class we will identify these corners as         */
    /* lowLeft and upperRight                                   */
    
    
protected function setupMultilineTextflow($lowLeftX, $lowLeftY, $upperRightX, $upperRightY,
                        $fontName, $fontEncoding, $fontSize, $text){
        
        $orderDetails = 'Datum:
        Auftrags-NR:
        Auftragsname:
        Kunden-Nr:';

        $textFlow = PDF_create_textflow($this->pdf, $text, 
                    "fontname=".$fontName." 
                    fontsize=".$fontSize." 
                    encoding=".$fontEncoding);
        PDF_fit_textflow($this->pdf, $textFlow3, $lowLeftX, $lowLeftY, $upperRightX, $upperRightY,"");
        
    }
    
    protected function setupTable($headers=array('test'=>''), array $field){        
                }
    
}
?>
```

This class is called from a following

```
class PDF extends AbstractPDF{
    
    public function __construct(){
        
        parent::__construct();
        
        parent::startAFourPage();
        
    }
    
    public function generateContent(){
        
        return "";
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I apologize for having so much code, but I wanted to draw a full picture.

The issue is that when I try to call these classes I get a following error:

> 2017/12/19 18:47:58 [error] 465#465: *252 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDFlibException: Function must not be called in 'object' scope in/var/www/dev-vm-stretch.de/htdocs/AbstractPDF.php:30
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/www/dev-vm-stretch.de/htdocs/AbstractPDF.php(30): pdf_begin_page_ext(Resource id #1, 0, 0, 'width=a4.width ...')
>
> #1 /var/www/dev-vm-stretch.de/htdocs/PDF.php(10): AbstractPDF->startAFourPage()
>
> #2 /var/www/dev-vm-stretch.de/htdocs/index.php(18): PDF->__construct()
>
> #3 {main}
>
> thrown in /var/www/dev-vm-stretch.de/htdocs/AbstractPDF.php on line 30" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.34.51, server: dev-vm-stretch.de, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "dev-vm-stretch.de"

I think that is because I separated the PDFLib related code into functions, but I am not 100% sure as my PDFLib experience is limited to slightly more then 5 days and I haven't found any PDFLib tutorials that would deal with these kind of issues :-(

Any ideas on how this error could be fixed are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is simple. You can only create a page, when you have an output document. You create a new output document, with `begin_document($file, $options);` You might at this as well to `__construct`.

You might check **PDFlib 9.1.1 API reference**, chapter 1.2 "Function Scopes". Also all PDFlib PHP samples (including in the PDFlib PHP package), demonstrate the correct usage.

Comment: I actually had that line in the test files I'm using for tests and as samples to pull to various pieces... And I absolutely missed it :-(

Thanks